NextJS14 finds the slug "favicon.ico" in a server side function
I am building a shop frontend in NextJS 14 with the app router. It should support SSR, so I divided the shop page into page.tsx (for serverside fetching, see below) and a HomeClient.tsx, which handles the reactivity.
So far, so good. But now I face a strange problem.
import React from 'react';
import HomeClient from './HomeClient';
import Product from '@app/types/Product';

const fetchProducts = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        cache: 'no-store',
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return {
        products: data as Product[],
        totalPages: data.totalPages,
    };
};

const HomePage = async ({ params, searchParams }) => {

    const localSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    const localParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

    const categoryPart = localParams.toString().replace('slug', 'category')
    const filterPart = localSearchParams.toString()

    let finalApiUrl = "";

    if (filterPart.length > 0) {
        finalApiUrl = categoryPart + '?' + filterPart;
    } else {
        finalApiUrl = categoryPart;
    }
    const fullApiUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/products?${finalApiUrl}`

    console.log('params', params)
    const category = params.slug || '';

    const page = parseInt(searchParams.page as string, 10) || 1;

    //const { data: initialData, totalPages: initialTotalPages } = await fetchProducts(finalApiUrl);
    const { products: initialProducts } = await fetchProducts(fullApiUrl)

    return (
        <HomeClient
            initialProducts={initialProducts}
            initialPage={page}
            initialCategory={category}
        />
    );
};

export default HomePage;


when i call the url http://localhost:3000/shop/tables, the console.log(params) prints
params { slug: 'favicon.ico' }

i already added a favicon.ico to /public
and i added this in the layout
<Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
</Head>

but nothing helped.
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance
Adrian

I found the reason myself:
Reason: If NextJS has no favicon.ico set, modern browsers pull it on their own. thats why the slug is favicon
Solution: Put favicon.ico to /app and add
import Head from "next/head";

<Head>
   <link rel="icon" href="/src/app/favicon.ico"/>
</Head>

to the layout.tsx
after this, the slug is correct.
Cheers
Adrian
